# More elegant way of keeping count of records in multiple data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to keep a weekly count of the number of records in a number of data extensions, in another data extension. But the limitations of SFMC's SQL are too much for my limited knowledge of SQL, so currently I ended up creating a series of SQL queries:

1. SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Date
   as an Update action on my target DE, so it will create a new record if the query is run on a 'new' date. (come to think of it, this one isn't needed, I think?)
2. SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Date, COUNT(*) FROM Source_DE
   as an Update action on my target DE, to update the record of 'today' with a count.

And I repeat this for a few more DE's.

I've searched for better ways to do it, but every other solution I've found is simply not possible in SFMC. While this works, is there a more elegant way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [DataExtensionRowCount()](https://ampscript.guide/DataExtensionRowCount) AMPscript function.  In order to make it more useful, you can wrap it in a SSJS function like this:

```javascript
function getDERowCount(DEName) {
  
    var rowCount = 0;

    try {
      
      rowCount = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent("%"+"%"+"=DataExtensionRowCount"+"(\""+DEName+"\")="+"%"+"%");
      
    } catch(e3) {
      
      if (debug) {Write("<br>e3: " + Stringify(e3))}

      return 0;
      
    }
    
    return rowCount;
  
}
```

If you include this in a Script Activity on a CloudPage you could iterate through a list of DEs and output their size.

I use this function (along with a [folder path](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/b6fa8b82789aa6d09df6c1ee4c59b433) one) to maintain a Data Extension inventory DE.  It's a helpful data-set for reporting and inventory.

Comment: I am a complete novice to SSJS, or to JS in general, it somehow doesn't compute in my brain :D But perhaps I could try it!

This does require you to visit the CloudPage, correct? Because I want to execute the counts at a regular interval (I've now set up an automation with that series of SQL queries which executes every Monday 6am to keep a weekly count).

Comment: You can develop it in a CloudPage and implement it in a Script Activity in your Automation.  Both the CloudPage and Script Activity will let you run the SSJS code.